# Does the iTunes Affiliate Program work with the Volume Purchase Program?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

Can one earn affiliate commission through the [iTunes Affiliate Program](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-app-store-affiliate-program.html) for purchases made through Apple's Volume Purchase Programs for [Business](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/) or [Education](http://www.apple.com/education/volume-purchase-program/)?

In case it makes a difference, we're based in the U.S., so we would be using the LinkShare-powered program.

Comment: Did you ask them ?

Comment: Note sure who to ask. Apple's pretty hands-off with the affiliate program. Maybe LinkShare?

Answer (score 1):

That would be called Double dipping.

As Volume purchasing ([authorized](http://www.apple.com/education/volume-purchase-program/faq.html)) user you get the benefits of Volume purchase.

Means, you have to register with [Volume Purchase account](http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/volume/us/terms.html), that is not the same as the associate account.

You can not get at the same time the affiliate commission on top.

Comment: I think he's asking about getting a commission for volume purchases by others, not his own organization.

Comment: Exactly, as a developer, I'm interested in tracking Volume purchases via affiliate links, but I don't know if that would work. I can't find anything in the Apple docs to answer it definitively one way or the other.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/contact/